# How to find all combinations of DataFrame rows?

Tags: python, pandas, combinations

Im sorry if this question is similar to others asked in this forum, but I could not find a question similar enough. I have a df with 9 colums and 3 rows and I want to find all possible combinations between these rows. I have tried to use combinations from the itertools package but i can't seem to make it work.
My desired output would be a list of all possible combinations. Thank you and sorry if it's similar to other questions asked.

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Main1": ["Outcome1", "Outcome2", "Outcome3"],
                    "Main2": ["Outcome1", "Outcome2", "Outcome3"],
                    "Main3": ["Outcome1", "Outcome2", "Outcome3"],
                    "Main4": ["Outcome1", "Outcome2", "Outcome3"],
                    "Main5": ["Outcome1", "Outcome2", "Outcome3"],
                    "Main6": ["Outcome1", "Outcome2", "Outcome3"],
                    "Main7": ["Outcome1", "Outcome2", "Outcome3"],
                    "Main8": ["Outcome1", "Outcome2", "Outcome3"],
                    "Main9": ["Outcome1", "Outcome2", "Outcome3"]})

    Main1   Main2   Main3   Main4   Main5   Main6   Main7   Main8   Main9
0   Outcome1    Outcome1    Outcome1    Outcome1    Outcome1    Outcome1    Outcome1    Outcome1    Outcome1
1   Outcome2    Outcome2    Outcome2    Outcome2    Outcome2    Outcome2    Outcome2    Outcome2    Outcome2
2   Outcome3    Outcome3    Outcome3    Outcome3    Outcome3    Outcome3    Outcome3    Outcome3    Outcome3

all_combinations = list(combinations(df1, 3))
```

edit: Smaller sample and desired output:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Main1": ["Outcome1", "Outcome2", "Outcome3"], "Main2": ["Outcome1", "Outcome2", "Outcome3"]})
```

desired output something like this :

```
[["Outcome1","Outcome1"], ["Outcome1","Outcome2"], ["Outcome1","Outcome3"], ["Outcome2","Outcome1"], ["Outcome2","Outcome2"], ["Outcome2","Outcome3"], ["Outcome3","Outcome1"], ["Outcome3","Outcome2"], ["Outcome3","Outcome3"]]
```

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: Hi! A list of all combinations of outcomes. Example : First combination would be only Outcome1 in every row, second combo would be only Outcome2 in every row, third combination would be Outcome2 in first row and Outcome1 in every other row etc etc. Sorry for being unclear

Comment: Perhaps post a smaller sample and show the outcome of that sample.

Comment: Good idea. @RichieV I updated the post with a smaller sample and example output. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, it seems you want each output to have as many items as columns in your df... but in your first example you attempted to get outputs of 3 items (as many ROWS in the df)... which is it? or perhaps it will be clearer if you post a real sample from your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a cartesian product of a list with itself.

```
from itertools import product

options = ['Outcome1', 'Outcome2', 'Outcome3']

result = product(options, options)
print(*result, sep='\n')
```

Output

```
('Outcome1', 'Outcome1')
('Outcome1', 'Outcome2')
('Outcome1', 'Outcome3')
('Outcome2', 'Outcome1')
('Outcome2', 'Outcome2')
('Outcome2', 'Outcome3')
('Outcome3', 'Outcome1')
('Outcome3', 'Outcome2')
('Outcome3', 'Outcome3')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use List comprehension

```
>>> [[i,j] for i in df1.Main1 for j in df1.Main2]
[['Outcome1', 'Outcome1'], ['Outcome1', 'Outcome2'], ['Outcome1', 'Outcome3'], [
'Outcome2', 'Outcome1'], ['Outcome2', 'Outcome2'], ['Outcome2', 'Outcome3'], ['O
utcome3', 'Outcome1'], ['Outcome3', 'Outcome2'], ['Outcome3', 'Outcome3']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using itertools product

**For smaller Dataframe**

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

# Define dataframe
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Main1": ["Outcome1", "Outcome2", "Outcome3"], "Main2": ["Outcome1", "Outcome2", "Outcome3"]}) 

# Take product of row values
# Once transposed, all the columns are the rows are the same
# We take the value of first row, and repeat to get the desired product
all_combinations = list(product(np.transpose(df1.values)[0], repeat=2))

# Show result
from pprint import pprint as pp
pp(all_combinations)
```

**Output**

```
[('Outcome1', 'Outcome1'),
 ('Outcome1', 'Outcome2'),
 ('Outcome1', 'Outcome3'),
 ('Outcome2', 'Outcome1'),
 ('Outcome2', 'Outcome2'),
 ('Outcome2', 'Outcome3'),
 ('Outcome3', 'Outcome1'),
 ('Outcome3', 'Outcome2'),
 ('Outcome3', 'Outcome3')]
```

**For Original DataFrame**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Main1": ["Outcome1", "Outcome2", "Outcome3"],
                    "Main2": ["Outcome1", "Outcome2", "Outcome3"],
                    "Main3": ["Outcome1", "Outcome2", "Outcome3"],
                    "Main4": ["Outcome1", "Outcome2", "Outcome3"],
                    "Main5": ["Outcome1", "Outcome2", "Outcome3"],
                    "Main6": ["Outcome1", "Outcome2", "Outcome3"],
                    "Main7": ["Outcome1", "Outcome2", "Outcome3"],
                    "Main8": ["Outcome1", "Outcome2", "Outcome3"],
                    "Main9": ["Outcome1", "Outcome2", "Outcome3"]})
all_combinations = list(product(np.transpose(df1.values)[0], repeat=3))

pp(all_combinations)
```

**Output**

```
[('Outcome1', 'Outcome1', 'Outcome1'),
 ('Outcome1', 'Outcome1', 'Outcome2'),
 ('Outcome1', 'Outcome1', 'Outcome3'),
 ('Outcome1', 'Outcome2', 'Outcome1'),
 ('Outcome1', 'Outcome2', 'Outcome2'),
 ('Outcome1', 'Outcome2', 'Outcome3'),
 ('Outcome1', 'Outcome3', 'Outcome1'),
 ('Outcome1', 'Outcome3', 'Outcome2'),
 ('Outcome1', 'Outcome3', 'Outcome3'),
 ('Outcome2', 'Outcome1', 'Outcome1'),
 ('Outcome2', 'Outcome1', 'Outcome2'),
 ('Outcome2', 'Outcome1', 'Outcome3'),
 ('Outcome2', 'Outcome2', 'Outcome1'),
 ('Outcome2', 'Outcome2', 'Outcome2'),
 ('Outcome2', 'Outcome2', 'Outcome3'),
 ('Outcome2', 'Outcome3', 'Outcome1'),
 ('Outcome2', 'Outcome3', 'Outcome2'),
 ('Outcome2', 'Outcome3', 'Outcome3'),
 ('Outcome3', 'Outcome1', 'Outcome1'),
 ('Outcome3', 'Outcome1', 'Outcome2'),
 ('Outcome3', 'Outcome1', 'Outcome3'),
 ('Outcome3', 'Outcome2', 'Outcome1'),
 ('Outcome3', 'Outcome2', 'Outcome2'),
 ('Outcome3', 'Outcome2', 'Outcome3'),
 ('Outcome3', 'Outcome3', 'Outcome1'),
 ('Outcome3', 'Outcome3', 'Outcome2'),
 ('Outcome3', 'Outcome3', 'Outcome3')]
​
```